# What is the Main contrast between classical coin toss and superposition state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, probability, superposition, determinism

We know that in normal coin-toss there is two probable states HEAD OR TAIL. When we commence for measuring only get head or tail,is it means two probable states collapse into one {H or T}.in mathematical language we have called it mutually exclusive(not simultaneous) but but but in QM simultaneously two states possible right? From that sense, is QM weird

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this two stories Coin succession and qm observable same?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the Main contrast between classical coin toss and superposition state?

One big difference is that if you toss a coin twice in quick succession the outcome of the second coin toss is independent of the first - the outcomes are uncorrelated and you are just as likely to get HH as to get HT. When you measure an observable in a quantum system twice in quick succession, the result of the second observation is correlated with the first, and you can increase the correlation by reducing the time  interval between the measurements.